# Did Dolores abandon/forget this important goal?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

** SPOILER warning for season 3 finale of *Westworld* **

In the season 3 finale it is revealed that Dolores' plan was not to destroy the humans, but to save them. And she does this by giving Caleb, a human, the choice. (just like Ford gave her the choice that led to hosts freedom). This I understand, it's well explained by her final dialogue with Maeve.

However her motivation, her main goal was to create a world for hosts. And she repeats this mid-season to Maeve, promising she is fighting for a world for all hosts, not just for herself.

However in the finale it seems that she initially wanted to destroy the humans **only** because of her anger towards humans. And now the anger is gone, she chooses to see the beauty in mankind and thus changes her mind on destroying the world. But what about her goal and promises of making hosts live free in the real world by taking it from the humans? She doesn't touch on that at all in the finale.